# How to change a seaborn histogram plot to work for hours of the day?

Tags: pandas, time-series, seaborn, histogram

I have a pandas dataframe with lots of time intervals of varying start times and lengths. I am interested in the distribution of start times over 24hours. I therefore have another column entitled Hour with just that in. I have plotted a histogram using seaborn to look at the distribution but obviously the x axis starts at 0 and runs to 24. I wonder if there is a way to change so it runs from 8 to 8 and loops over at 23 to 0 so it provides a better visualisation of my data from a time perspective. Thanks in advance.

```
sns.distplot(df2['Hour'], bins = 24, kde = False).set(xlim=(0,23))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a custom order of x-values on your bar plot, I'd suggest using `matplotlib` directly and plot your histogram simply as a bar plot with `width=1` to get rid of padding between bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# prepare sample data
dates = pd.date_range(
    start=datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    end=datetime(2020, 1, 7),
    freq="H")

random_dates = np.random.choice(dates, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"date":random_dates})

df["hour"] = df["date"].dt.hour

# set your preferred order of hours
hour_order = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# calculate frequencies of each hour and sort them
plot_df = (
    df["hour"]
    .value_counts()
    .rename_axis("hour", axis=0)
    .reset_index(name="freq")
    .set_index("hour")
    .loc[hour_order]
    .reset_index())

# day / night colour split
day_mask = ((8 <= plot_df["hour"]) & (plot_df["hour"] <= 20))
plot_df["color"] = np.where(day_mask, "skyblue", "midnightblue")

# actual plotting - note that you have to cast hours as strings
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.bar(
    x=plot_df["hour"].astype(str),
    height=plot_df["freq"],
    color=plot_df["color"], width=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Hour')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Really very kind of you and completely answered my question as well as some extra bits. The colour variations are fantastic. Is there any way to do three colours (perhaps deepening shades of blue for example) for daytime, night time and then a subsection of night in an even darker colour? Harder than two I guess as it would have to be more complicated than using np.where. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sure, you can nest `np.where` like so `np.where(condition_1, color_1, np.where(condition_2, color_2, color_3)` or do the updates in a separate call for each condition like so: `plot_df.loc[condition_1, 'color'] = color_1`